# What is the use of n in the ggplot aes() function R?

Tags: r

I have a code as below. n is defined for the y axis. what does n mean here.

```
orders %>% count(order_number) %>% ggplot(aes(order_number,n))
```

Regards,
Philip

Comment: `count()` counts how many observations you have for each level of `order_number`, and puts the result in the column, `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write that would be

```
data <- orders %>% count(order_number)

ggplot(data, aes(x = order_number,y = n))
```

And so here you're creating data with two columns, order_number and n. Then you're plotting that data with `ggplot` and in the `aes` parentheses you are specifying one variable for the x axis and one for the y axis.